# javascript, wrap first 200 characters in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

im making an accordion for a client.
there website is built on .net, something of which i have no idea how it works.

my current accordion is something similar too...

```
<h1>Header</h1>
<span class="content">Content here</span>
```

I need something more like

```
<h1>Header</h1>
<span class="entry-content">summary  here</span>
<span class="content">Content here</span>
```

I want the 'entry-content' to show initially and when the h1 is clicked the 'content' div slides down.

As its in .net all the content is pulled from the following line...

```
<%#Eval("Information")%>
```

is there a way with JS i can wrap the first 200 characters in a div, and the rest can be wrapped in another div?

I hope this makes sense!

Comment: Why not just use `.substring(0, 200)` to get the substring for the first span? Am I missing some thing?

Answer (score 0):

I thinks this might do the trick http://jsfiddle.net/UX3sC/

Comment: thanks circadian! is there a way to then wrap the rest of the text in another div?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the section [javascript, wrap first 200 characters in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332331/javascript-wrap-first-200-characters-in-a-div/7332468#7332468)

Dion Jones: you are already doing that with Circadians code, it will give you the HTML markup:

```
<h1>Header</h1>
<span class="entry-content">summary  here</span>
<span class="content">Content here</span>
```

Or you want the markup to look any other way?